# Rename all Items in a directory

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a directory which has about 50 files and I would like to prepend "CD1" to all the file names. After reading [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1). I came up with the following command (using PowerShell ISE on Windows 10):

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {'CD1' + $_.Name}
```

but that prepended "CD1" several times to each file name. I also got the error:

```
Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path.
At line:1 char:17
+ Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {'CD1' + $_.Name}
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\TOOdhm...CD1CD1CD149.mp3:String) [Rename-Item], DirectoryNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

It seemed like it didn't know when to stop iterating through the directory so I used the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet and tried this:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item -NewName {('CD1' + $_.Name)} }
```

which did nothing and gave the error

> Rename-Item : Cannot evaluate parameter 'NewName' because its argument is specified as a script block and there is no input. A script block cannot be evaluated without input.

Does any one have any clue why I am getting this issue? I could have manually renamed the files by now but both these commands should work. I even found a website where they used an example with almost exactly(I think in their example they may be appending) these commands in this format and it's bugging me that they don't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to avoid getting already renamed items processed again is to enclose Get-ChildItem in parentheses.

```
(Get-ChildItem) | Rename-Item -NewName {'CD1'+ $_.name}
```

To avoid another prepend on successive runs exclude files beginning with `CD1`

```
Get-ChildItem | Where {$_.Name -notmatch '^CD1'} | Rename-Item -NewName {'CD1'+ $_.name}
```

Or

```
gci -Exclude CD1* | Ren -NewName {'CD1'+ $_.name}
```

Comment: thanks i should have thought of these workarounds. Good to know about the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

In your second attempt, you're using braces for a script-block where you don't need one.
The following worked for me

```
 Get-ChildItem | % {Rename-Item -NewName ('CD1'+ $_.Name) -Path $_.Name}
```

Note the extra -Path to repeat the current path of the file.

Comment: I tried that but I got the same result where the multiple `CD1`s are in the title.

Comment: perhaps your previous run succeeded and the files already had CD1 in them? I ran this and every file got one CD1 prepended.

Comment: nope I ran the command `Get-ChildItem -Filter "*CD1*" |Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace 'CD1',''}` every time after to remove the extra `CD1`s from the title.

Comment: so they got renamed incorrectly and I got this error: `Rename-Item : Could not find a part of the path. at <directory location`. 

`At line:1 char:20
+ ... t-ChildItem | % {Rename-Item -NewName ('CD1'+ $_.Name) -Path $_.Name} ` where the `{Rename-Item -NewName ('CD1'+ $_.Name) -Path $_.Name}` section is underlined